# Can't connect to my default gateway on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, router, gateway, upnp

I need to access my router's web interface (default: 192.168.0.1, pinged and confirmed) to enable UPnP.
But I can't connect to it.

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp9s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp9s0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0.0 U     600    0        0 wlp9s0
```

Comment: Is the router working correctly? Did you succeed in accesing the web interface before? (Anyway, I would try a reboot if you didn't do it yet)

Comment: I never tried to access it before. By rebooting do you mean resetting the router? I would do that only as a last resort.

Comment: So, you really don't know whether the router has a web interface enabled or not, you are assuming it does. (By rebooting I mean shut it down and switch it on again)

Comment: No. I know that the my router has a web interface. It's a CISCO model and there are how-to guides about its web interface. Rebooting didn't work